# How do I programmatically access the filesystem of an iOS device connected to a Windows desktop?

Tags: iphone, c++, windows, itunes

I want to access the Documents folder of an application on an iPhone or iOS device by using C++.  There are many programs that can access the filesystem of an iOS device, such as [iPhone Explorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iphoneexplorer/), so I know this is possible.

These programs need iTunes, so I think I have to communicate with iTunes to access some folders in iPhone device.

I'm using both Visual C++ and Embarcadero C++ Builder. However, I can't find any resources to access the iOS device filesystem using C++.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: So let me get this straight: you want to run an application on your Windows desktop, which should then access the Documents folder of an app on your connected iPhone ?

Comment: I'm making a music player app for iPhone, and i want to make Windows application which can access the Document folder of music player app.

Comment: [MobileDevice framework](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/MobileDevice_Library)

Answer (score 0):

iTunes includes a type library that you can use to access its object model.  I don't remember the specifics, but you can use something like OleView to view the library and you can #import it in your C++ project.

I've only even done this to access the library management features, so I'm not sure if it provides an object model for iOS devices or not (though I would assume it would).